# Accessing a general structure member using a variable

Tags: c, struct

Not entirely sure my question title describes what I want to do, but couldn't think how better to word it!!  I'm using C, and perhaps the pseudocode below will describe what I'm trying to do:

```
typedef struct obj
{
    char *str1;
    char *str2;
    char *str3;
} object;

/* global variable */
object *glob;

void black_box_function(local, member) ????
{
    /* Do something with glob->member and local->member */
}

void main()
{
    object *ob1, *ob2;

    /* Initialise glob, ob1 and ob2 somewhere */

    black_box_function(ob1, str1);
    black_box_function(ob2, str3);

}
```

Hopefully, you can see what I'm trying to do. I have a "black-box" function that will do something with a particular member, and I need to be able to tell the black-box function which member to use.

I don't want to just pass the member directly to the function, like in this code, as that won't fit into the rest of my code easily.

```
black_box_function(ob1->member, glob->member)
```

Comment: If your members are really called `str1`, `str2`, etc. (which I appreciate may just be as illustration), then why not use an array, and pass an index into the function?

Comment: Yes, illustration.  Actually, I'm using code other people have written that I can't easily change.  So I need to stick with the structure definitions as they currently exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following magic (with GCC extensions):

```
#define black_box(local, member)  black_box_function((local), __builtin_offsetof(object, member))

void black_box_function(object *local, int offset)
{
    char *lmember = ((void *)local) + offset;
    char *gmember = ((void *)global) + offset;
    /* do stuff */
}
```

However, you must know in advance the type of your members.  Keep in mind that C is not a dynamically typed language, so you have no runtime introspection at all.

**EDIT:** You can implement `offsetof()` functionality without resorting to GCC extensions, like this:

```
#define offsetof(type, field) ((int) (unsigned long) &((type *) 0)->field)
```

Comment: +1. Even though you use GCC Extensions, this is nearest to the OP's request!

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Thanks, the `offsetof` functionality can be implemented with pointer casting magic, without extensions.  I used the builtin GCC version for brevity

Comment: Why did you remove GCC Extension method? Keep both of them. Name them as Method 1 and Method 2. My +1 was for your GCC extensionmethod :)

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Oh, sorry.  I'll put it back

Comment: I like that suggestion as well - think it would work nicely - thanks!

Comment: Hold on! I think there is a problem with your [offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) macro. It's not returning the offset but the base address. You've missed the subtraction I guess

Comment: Have you tested it? I have.  Hint: there is a cast from zero to a pointer type so there is no need for substraction.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could create accessor functions for your struct and pass those accessors as function pointer arguments instead of passing the members directly

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} foo;

typedef int* (*accessor)(foo*);

int* get_a(foo* f) { return &f->a; }
int* get_b(foo* f) { return &f->b; }

void black_box_function(foo* object, accessor fn)
{
    int* p = fn(object);
}

int main(void)
{
    foo bar1;
    foo bar2;

    black_box_function(&bar1, get_a);
    black_box_function(&bar2, get_b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like that suggestion - think it would work nicely - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since all are  char*, you can redefine the struct like:

```
typedef struct obj
{
    char **str; // Array of c
} object;
```

Then you can send the index of `str` from main which you want work with:

```
black_box_function(obj1, index)
```

So you can it like `obj1->str[i]` in your blackbox.

Btw, `black-box_function` will not compile.

On a side note: A little more info/code on your blackbox function and compilable code would give a better picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: All are char* in my example, but not necessarily in my real code.  I tried to distill the essence of my question into something simple ...

Thanks for suggestion though ...